# Android studio show only selected application don't work and not filter package

Tags: android

I'm new hope to expose the problem well.
Sometimes in my Android Studio the log filter for the app that I'm testing does not work, is that I put "show only selected application" or "edit filter configuration" package, you still see all the logs and not just those of my app.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can select option show only selected and select your application

Comment: thanks for your answer :) . "show only selected application" don't work, but I solved the problem by setting the PID in the "edit filter configuration"